# cin.fail error handling issues

Tags: c++, cin

I have a little program, and I want to evaluate input. The input for the N variable should only be a number between 1 and 2000. Now, the below code that I wrote works fine if I put in correct/incorrect numbers, but when I put in some random letters (I have to make sure that there's only numbers, so I have to handle if someone puts in letters), the prompt gets written out as many times as much letters I've put in, and I only want it to be put out once. So if I write 34, it works. If I write 3355453, the input gets checked and the user gets prompted to try again with a number between 1 and 2000. When I write a letter 'x', the the input gets checked and the user gets prompted to try again with a number between 1 and 2000 again, but if I write more letters, for example xxxx - the prompt appears 4 times instead of one. If i put in 7 letters, the propt appears 7 times. Any way to solve this? Thank you!

```
do {
  cout << "Please put in a number between 1 and 2000."   <<     endl;
  cin >> N;

  if(cin.fail() || N<1 || N>2000){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
  }
} while(cin.fail() || N<1 || N>2000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `cin.ignore()` w/ `cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');`

Comment: What kind of magic is this? :D Thank you, what does this exactly do? Apart from working :D

Comment: Pls take a look at the doc http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/. By default the call to ignore only ignores *one* character or till it encounters EOF, in our case we shall ignore as many characters as we can (MAX_INT is by far large enough) till we encounter/reach to the end-of-line symbol ('\n') which was entered by the user.